# How to redirect in Play Framework?

Tags: redirect, playframework

When I call other action in one action, it also display itself template, in Play 1.1 RC
and when I `Redirect("...url")` but it does not work, is there someone that can help me?

Comment: show your code, clarify your answer, very poorly worded right now.

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the answers above, here's how you redirect to an external url:

public static void index() {
    redirect("http://geeks.aretotally.in");
}

Answer (score 6):

To redirect, you simply call the action.  From the example in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/5things#a2.RedirecttoanactionbycallingthecorrespondingJavamethoda):

```
public static void show(Long id) {
    Article article = Article.findById(id);
    render(article);
}

public static void edit(Long id, String title) {
    Article article = Article.findById(id);
    article.title = title;
    article.save();
    show(id);
}
```

At the end of the edit action, the call to show(...) will cause a redirect on the client's browser as if they had hit the same URL that routes to the show method.

Comment: oh.. That is some major magic. How does that work? And are there other examples for Play doing things that the Java source code does not indicate at all?

Comment: Play! uses a bytecode enhancer to modify your compiled code behind the scenes. Aside from using it to handle redirects, it also uses it to provide property support in database entities.  For example you can call "foo.bar = 5;" and behind the scenes it maps to "foo.setBar(5);" and "return foo.bar;" maps to "foo.getBar();".

Answer (score 6):

Since none of these answers provide a general/reusable method to do this, here is my code.  This allows you to create any number of redirects in the `conf/routes` file without creating a controller for each.

Yes, this is trivial, but perhaps it is of use to someone.

conf/routes:

```
GET     /admin     Application.redirect(url:'/admin/index.html')
```

app/controllers/Application.java:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void redirect(String url) {
        redirect(url, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the play framework, when you call an action, by default it renders the template associated with that action.

For example, a Contoller named Application

```
public static void index()
```

Will render

```
app/views/Application/index.html
```

To make it render a different view, then you can specify the template as the first parameter in the render method.

So,

```
renderTemplate("Application/myOtherTemplate.html");
```

Redirect should only really be used if you are redirecting to a URL outside of your application.

Comment: def logout() = {
    register
  }

  def register() = {
    logger.debug("call")
    Template
  }